# Handling measurement units in NSTextField

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I am creating a test application to calculate the area of a rectangle.This application uses  **NSTextField** control to get the length and breadth of rectangle.
The user is expected to enter a string value which will include units of length as well (Sample Values **2.5 inches**, **1500 mm**).
I want NSTextField to convert the value in centimeters (**cm**) automatically so that it displays the converted value (**in cm**) as soon as the text field looses focus.

**For Eg:**

**User Enters length as**:  1500 mm

As soon as user goes to next text field to enter breadth, the length field displays

**Displayed Value**:  150 cm

How can we achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to use the delegate method, controlTextDidEndEditing:, which is sent to your text field's delegate when the editing is finished.  Once you get the string from the field editor, you'll need to parse it somehow to find the units (how you parse it depends on what all you need to find). If you have a small number of things you're hunting for, like cm, mm, m, then you could probably just use rangeOfString: and test for 0 length to find out what units were entered. BTW, you should do your math correctly too -- 1500mm = 150 cm

Answer (score 0):

I would consider a different approach, using a UIPicker to display the available units, and have them enter the number separately.

Otherwise, you'll have to do all this parsing.  Don't see the point of parsing.  Plus, if they make a mistake spelling the units, or use different ways of indicating it, then you would have to account for that as well.  Depends on your application, but if the user has to type the units out anyway, it might be more convenient for them to use a UIPicker.

Comment: As this app is a POC for one of my projects so I will have to insist on using NSTextField.

Comment: OK, well then, you just need to use methods in NSString to parse the text.  You'll want to take a look at the methods in the NSString reference, especially under the heading "Finding Characters and Substrings".  It's pretty easy to extract numbers from strings.  You can extract the numeric part using -doubleValue (or -integerValue if you're not allowing decimals).  Then you can search for the unit string by removing the number/whitespace or searching for whitespace after number.  Then you just need to determine which unit is represented in the unit string, based on some list.  And so on.

Comment: I was able to accomplish this by sub-classing NSTextField and overriding -(BOOL)textShouldEndEditing but the problem is that each object of that sub-class will exhibit the same behavior. So currently I am looking to implement it by sub-classing NSFormatter.